# Android Studio icons meaning

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to add flavors to my project in the gradle file, but can't because my src folder is not just a folder, and I can't make another folder within it. I can only create packages. Can you explain to me why this is happening? I tried to recreate this folder many times, but I had no success.

[image]

Java folder comes automatically after selection of build variant from package:

```
production.java.com.bigblueclip.picstitch
```