# Why are gradle files icons showing a rat?

Tags: android, gradle

My `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` file is showing a rat icon, as circled in this image. Why is this icon used?

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio file list with Gradle icons highlighted]

Comment: It's not a rat. It's an elephant. It's Gradle's logo.

Comment: Funny question though

Comment: Nice way to take revenge if you are a gradle victim :)

Comment: Related [Android Studio icons meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25991228/7666442)

Comment: it's a  Rorschach test

Comment: Actually i can't understand the meaning of this icon , as before this there was an other icon

Comment: That link have no answer.

Comment: yeah, but in intellij it looks more like a rat than an elephant due to its tiny size

Answer (score 3):

It is not rat it is Gradle's official logo basically. It comes with the Android studio 3.3.